# DomCrawler Symfony: how to get content from a node excluding children?

Tags: symfony, web-crawler

Lets say I have an html page like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    Hello World!
    <div> my other content </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How do i get "Hello World" from the DOM Crawler?

I thought this would work:

```
$crawler = $crawler
    ->filter('body > div');
    ->reduce(function (Crawler $node, $i) {
        return false;
    });
```

But this obviously will give an error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: "The current node list is empty"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't know if this can be done easier, but you could extract text node contents using XPath:

```
$crawler->filterXPath('//body/text()')->text();
```

Result will be a `string` containing `Hello World` and empty spaces before and after text until first tag. So if you want just the text itself you could trim the value:

```
$helloWorld = trim($crawler->filterXPath('//body/text()')->text());
```

This will work in your case, however, if you have multiple text nodes in the body, eg:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    Hello World!
    <div> my other content </div>
    Some other text
</body>
</html>
```

You might do:

```
$crawler->filterXPath('//body/text()')->extract(['_text']));
```

This will return an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>
        Hello World!

    [1] =>
        Some other text

)
```